# Checkmarx OS_Access_Violation on Python os.enviro, parseargs, and main

Tags: python, security, environment-variables, args, checkmarx

I'm getting an OS_Access_Violation in several places in source code across different python projects. It shows up in areas like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

often coupled with something like:

`os.makedirs(args.output_dir, exist_ok=True)`

as well as

```
 elif args.backend == "beefygoodness":
   os.environ["MMMMM_TACOS"] = "beefygoodness"
```

and

'args = parser.parse_args()'

There's no description associated with this finding, so I'm unsure what it means and what the proper remediation is. I'm also not sure if it's referring to an access violation in the developer sense (aka, program crash) or if it's a reference to data that shouldn't be accessible, or what exactly.

Google is no help on this either, unfortunately.

So does anyone know what this cryptic high-priority finding is referring to, and what the proper fix is? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such python exception or error. And there is absolutely nothing wrong with `sys.argv[1:]` even if `argv` contains nothing but the program name or path. The error is not from python. Google shows a few mentions of this error, such as https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/common-src-AMDTOSWrappers/blob/master/Include/osExceptionReason.h. You've probably omitted some critical information such as the platform you're using and the literal error you're seeing.

Comment: This is a CheckMarx static analysis security finding in the Python code, not an error from Python itself.

Comment: @ChopperCharles Is this a local script, or something that is open to users through the web or other means?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the query yet, but the result make sense.

You use the input that came from the user, so you have no certainty about its integrity, and it can be hostile.

For example:

`args[1:]`: You expect for 4 arguments, but the user can give you more, and unexpectedly affect the system.

Now, If I understand your question correctly, you said the vulnerable flow starts in `main` call and ends in one of `os` calls.

At this point you should understand that the unprotected input from the user, used as argument of `os` methods.

What if the user set `/root/pwd` as directory input?

Or what if the user set malicious text to the environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution is to save the arguments/env-variables as files [and credentials fetching from secret store vault] and consume those in runtime.